# My ubuntu 16.04 is not showing my intel hd graphics driver under additional drivers tab. It even shows no proprietary driver is in use

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, intel-hd

[image: screenshot of my softwares and update tab]
ubuntu 16.04 is unable to locate my intel hd graphics 5500. I'm facing lagging issues while watching HD videos.

Answer (score 1):

The linux graphics driver for intels HD graphics is not proprietary.

And for the rest of the drivers that are not listed you probably do not have any hardware that requires or can have proprietary drivers.

If you are certain you have hardware that requires a proprietary driver you probably need to download it from a source outside of the repositories and install it manually.